# Kafka KStreams - how to add threads / using StreamsConfig.NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I was messing about with this param and ran into some oddness. My app runs ok without it but when I added this line to the config:

```
 config.put(StreamsConfig.NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG, "3");
```

CPU usage wouldn't climb above zero. App didn't appear to be doing *anything*. No errors.

Is there some advised method to increasing thread usage for a KStreams app? Or just 'trust the force' and let it all run together?

---

### Edit:

1. I have two partitions
2. Have checked the consumer lag via `kafka-consumer-groups` - lots of records available
3. Even if there were only 1 partition - why would having multiple threads *do nothing*? 0% CPU.

Comment: That is indeed weird. Increasing parallelism via NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG should just work... Can you reliably reproduce this? Can you share setup and code details? I would like to reproduce it on my system.

Comment: Yes it's reproducible. My setup is v minimal (see my other posts on this - **steep learning curve**). Increasing the STREAM_THREAD value doesn't have 'useful' results. Are there any recommended values for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How many partitions do you have? If you only have a single partition then increasing the number of threads wont have any effect as the number of partitions defines the maximum parallelism. So if you have 1 partition and 3 threads, you'll only have 1 busy thread.

Check there is data available for consumption on the input topics. Make sure you have `StreamsConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG` set to `latest`. 
If you ran it previously with the same `applicationId` then Kafka Streams may have already consumed all of the data, so there will be nothing to do. In this case you could use a different `applicationId` or you could use the [Kafka Streams Reset Tool](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/bin/kafka-streams-application-reset.sh) to reset the topics.

This setting is used in some of the tests, i.e.,[KStreamRepartitionJoinTest](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/test/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/integration/KStreamRepartitionJoinTest.java) and seems to be working fine.

Comment: Im sure this will come down to a UFU.

Comment: Is there a guideline / rule-of-thumb  for threads vs separate instances for a given partition count? IE If I have 4 partitions am I better off with 4 threads, 2 threads in 2 instances or 4 instances? (each instance being on a separate machine)

Comment: The guideline is to use a single thread per instance. You still might have many instances on a single machine (obviously you don't want all the instances on a single machine).

Comment: I thought the guideline was one thread per cpu core, and one instance per machine. Multiple instances in one machine each with a single thread, would consume a lot of wasted JVM space